# Count how often a number occurs in the cell excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, numbers

I have a **list of numbers** in excel for example:

```
11111
12345
23222
13111
11511
92099
```

And I want to count the number of occurrence of the numbers
So it will be like this

```
11111 5
12345 0
23222 4
13111 4
11511 4
92099 3
```

Comment: The way described I would've expected count `1` for `12345` do you wish to count in case of duplicates only?

Comment: @P.b Yes, I have managed to do this using C# code but i needed it on Excel since my company won't allow .exe files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=LET(ξ,MAX(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,SEQUENCE(10,,0),""))),IF(ξ=1,0,ξ))`

Comment: Very creative solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using SUMPRODUCT and MODE.SNGL:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(MODE.SNGL(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))=--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))),0)
```

[image]

We can also use BYROW and LET to do the whole range at once:

```
=BYROW(
    A1:A6,
    LAMBDA(rg,
        LET(
            a,--MID(rg,SEQUENCE(LEN(rg)),1),
            IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(MODE.SNGL(a)=a)),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: `MODE.SNGLE` learned something new. I would've gone with a combination of MAX/FREQUENCY, but this is better

Comment: Still answered my version, since it works with non-numeric characters as well

Answer (score 1):

This works on any character, not just numbers:

```
=LET(d,B8,
     s,MID(d,SEQUENCE(LEN(d)),1),
     m,XMATCH(s,s),
     f,MAX(FREQUENCY(m,m)),
IF(f=1,0,f))
```

First an array (`s`) is made of each single character in the cell.

`m` creates an array of the match result of `s` to itself.

`f` returns the max number of the frequency of the matches.

Because this could return `1` for all unique values, an if-statement is added to change to `0` in case of `1`.

Or a combination of my and Scott Craner's solution making it alhanumeric usable:

```
=LET(d,B8,
     s,MID(d,SEQUENCE(LEN(d)),1),
     m,XMATCH(s,s),
IFERROR( SUM(--(MODE.SNGL(m)=m)) ,0))
```